# Characters are not displayed properly while setting up IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I was installing IDEA, the texts in the installer and later in the setup window weren't displayed properly, see pictures below.

Im on Windows 10. I do not have the standard Windows font, I set it to Bahnschrift, could this be the issue? I tried reinstalling, but it didn't help

[image]

The code is displaying normally

[image]

Comment: You could override default font in Appearance menu: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-appearance.html. Try to set default windows font (Segoe UI)

Comment: @Henry Windows 10, system language is English(US) and did not change the default settings in Idea

Comment: @y.bedrov thank you! Overriding default font worked, Although I had to change it to something else than Segoe UI, that one was the default one and unreadable.
Comic sans looking good as ever (jk)!